# add class to element from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid, addclass

I need to add a class (`.open`) to an element (`h2`) on another page from the home page depending on which option is clicked.

The jquery below shows a line of code that i've written which although doesn't work gives you an idea of what i'm trying to do.

Jquery

```
//open service section from home page

var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash != "") {
    var id = hash.substr(1); 
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block'; 
    //document.getElementById(id).previous('h2').addClass( "open" ); //CODE THAT DOESN'T WORK
}
```

HTML (This is what i'm trying to ahceive. As you can see the h2 contains the `.open` tag)

```
 <h2 class="section-heading toggle open">heading title</h2>
     <div id="content1" class="slide-content"></div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the DOM and jQuery. I suggest using one or the other.

The jQuery way to write the commented out "code that doesn't work" line is

```
$(hash).prev().first().addClass("open");
```

or

```
$(hash).prevAll('h2').first().addClass("open");
```

...if there's any chance of an element between the one with the ID and the `h2`.

Note I used `hash` rather than `id`, since it has the `#` on it, and conveniently that's how you select by `id` in CSS.